# Symfony2 having issues with multiple property in form types

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, entity

I'm pretty deep into a complex Symfony2 project, with many entities and join tables in forms etc. but I'm having a strange issue with the "multiple" attribute within the form builder.

Basically I have a form where a user can add an illness to the CRM, and each illness can be attached to a specific store (depending on the language used). There is a list of stores that can be chosen by the user within this form, and the values are stored in a join table. However I only want one store to be chosen (i.e. a select drop down) rather than a multiple select list but using the false value for the multiple attribute throws an error which I will outline later.

Firstly, here is the buildForm() code in my Type.php file:

```
        $builder->add('name' , 'text');
        $builder->add('description' , 'textarea');
        $builder->add('store', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Store',
                'empty_value' => 'Choose store',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
            ));
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            ),
        ));
```

And the entry for the store field in my Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Store", inversedBy="illness", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
public $store;
```

However, if I used the false declaration for the multiple attribute in the form Type, when the form is submitted I receive the following error:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

because it looks like it's passing the text value of the select box, rather than the relevant Entity. When set as a multiple select box (i.e. set to true) then it works fine and persists as it should.

My controller code:

```
    $addIllness = new Illness();

    $form = $this->createForm(new IllnessType($em), $addIllness);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($addIllness);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_illness_table'));

    }
```

Having it as a multiple select box is not the end of the world, though I'd rather have it as a drop down select so the user cannot select more than one store - rather than me having to add an error message or note to tell them otherwise.

If anyone has an ideas as to why this may be happening, or has encountered it before please let me know, I would be very grateful!

Thank you
Michael

Comment: "_because it looks like it's passing the text value of the select box_" Can you confirm this with the Symfony profiler (Profiler > forms > submitted data)? What happens if you remove the `multiple` option all together and allow it to default to `false`?

Comment: The submitted data I'm getting is Object(AppBundle\Entity\Store). I tried removing the option but I still get the same error regarding the spl_object_hash.